# The Rendered image look soo different from the preview

Tags: rendering

I've made some project and want to render it but the render image looks so different from what it looks on preview.

Heres the picture from the preview

### Preview Image

[image]

but the rendered Image looks like this

### Rendered Image

[image]

I know it hasnt done yet but it looks pretty much different for me

Comment: Hi :). Looks like a difference in lighting. Do you have the same HDRI set up in viewport and render?

Comment: @JachymMichal where do i check the lighting, Im new on blender T^T, and i use lighting using plane material that i give array modifier and change the surface to emission